# changing JSON value with other JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

on a nested JSON object, I would like to modify values and adding a JSON Object.
Assume a JSON Object like this:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": {
        "key2_1": "value2_2 ",
        "key2_2": {
            "key2_2_1 ": "value2_2_1"
        },
        "key2_3": "value2_3",
        "key2_4": {
            "key2_4_1": [{
                "key2_4_1_1a": "value2_4_1_1a",
                "key2_4_1_2a": "value2_4_1_2a"
            }, {
                "key2_4_1_1b": "value2_4_1_1b",
                "key2_4_1_2b": "value2_4_1_2b"
            }]
        }
    },
    "key3": {
        "key3_1": "value3_2 ",
        "key3_2": {
            "key3_2_1 ": "value3_2_1"
        },
        "key3_3": "value3_3",
        "key3_4": {
            "key3_4_1": {
                "key3_4_1_1": "value3_4_1_1"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

now the JSON will be recursive iterated to search for a specific value.
The replacement value can be a string

```
repl = 'MyString'
```

a dict string

```
repl = '''{"MyKey": [{"MyKey1": "MyValye1"},{"MyKey2": "MyValye2"}]}'''
```

or a list

```
repl = '''[{"MyKey1": "MyValye1"},{"MyKey2": "MyValye2"}]'''
```

so after I found the key where the replacement to add, I would like to replace the existing value for the given key.
eg for the string:

```
a[key] = repl
```

How I can do this for dict or list replacements?

The result could be depending on the replacement variable, the string eg in "key2_1", the dict in "key2_2_1" or the list in "key2_3". The keys where string,dict or list are inserted are examples.

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": {
        "key2_1": "MyString",
        "key2_2": {
            "key2_2_1 ": {"MyKey": [{"MyKey1": "MyValye1"},{"MyKey2": "MyValye2"}]}
        },
        "key2_3": [{"MyKey1": "MyValye1"},{"MyKey2": "MyValye2"}],
        "key2_4": {
            "key2_4_1": [{
                "key2_4_1_1a": "value2_4_1_1a",
                "key2_4_1_2a": "value2_4_1_2a"
            }, {
                "key2_4_1_1b": "value2_4_1_1b",
                "key2_4_1_2b": "value2_4_1_2b"
            }]
        }
    }

}
```

i have a search function:

```
def searchNreplace(data, search_val, replace_val):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        return [searchNreplace(listd, search_val, replace_val) for listd in data]
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        return {dictkey: searchNreplace(dictvalue, search_val, replace_val) for dictkey, dictvalue in data.items()}
    return replace_val if data == search_val else data

print(searchNreplace(data, "key3", repl))
```

Comment: So in result dict you want to have string or list/dict?

Comment: I clarify in the question. Sorry for not being accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really don't struggle with finding a key, you can use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library to parse your string to object and just assign it as `str`.

```
import json

repl = """{"MyKey": [{"MyKey1": "MyValye1"},{"MyKey2": "MyValye2"}]}"""
a[key] = json.loads(repl)
```

After that you can dump content back to file

```
with open("my_file", "w+") as f:
    json.dump(a, f)
```